# Value of variable not updating in Java NetBeans

Tags: java, variables, netbeans, access-specifier

I have two java files in same package. I want to take the updated value of one variable from one file to another. I wrote the following code. In class1.java :-

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
public class class1 {
    public static String bar = "Yes";
    static int age = 26;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        switch(age) {
            case 25: bar = "world";
                break;
            case 26: bar = "good";
                break;
            case 27: bar = "very";
                break;
            case 30: bar = "hello";
                break;
            default: JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

In class2.java :-

```
public class class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        class1 second = new class1();
        System.out.println(second.bar);
    }
}
```

The problem is that the final value is printed **Yes** which should not be printed. The output should be **good**. Please help me.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21155438/when-to-use-static-variables-methods-and-when-to-use-instance-variables-methods

Comment: Why can't you do this in constructor?

Comment: @bigbounty I don't know how to do that. Can you tell me how to do with constructor?

Comment: @UdayAgrawal I have answered in a better manner. Please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create a `class1` object, but you never run the `main` method. This means that the section of code never runs, and thus `bar` remains as `"Yes"`.

In `class2` insert `second.main(args);` before you print `second.bar` and you will get a *good* value.

Answer (score 1):

```
class class1 {

    public String getBar(String age){
        String bar = "Yes";
        switch(Integer.valueOf(age)) {
            case 25: bar = "world";
                break;
            case 26: bar = "good";
                break;
            case 27: bar = "very";
                break;
            case 30: bar = "hello";
                break;
        }
        return bar;
    }
}

public class class2 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
    String age = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Age Please");
    class1 class1Obj = new class1();
    System.out.println(class1Obj.getBar(age));
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is much better way to get the value of _var_ variable.

Comment: Though your answer is more tricky and better than previous, your answer do not give what exactly the solution is. So, I won't accept it as the answer. Thank you brother and sorry for this.